# How to actually use global state in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my company, all of the projects use at least some kind of global state library like Redux and MobX.

However, the actual usage is limited to storing fetched data, and it lacks any caching logic or mechanism. It's merely used to store the method for fetching data and the property for the fetched data.

Personally, I find this approach redundant because we could instead use something like `react-query`, which would not only accomplish the same task but also provide better caching capabilities.

For tasks like theming, we are already using MUI, which offers the `<ThemeProvider>` and `useTheme()` hook, eliminating the need for additional global state libraries.

Despite my confusion, I understand that there must be reasons for using global state libraries. However, I cannot identify any specific advantages. These libraries continue to have significant weekly downloads, indicating that there is likely a crucial aspect I am overlooking. I would appreciate it if you could share your insights and explain why global state is still necessary in React (in general, not just based on the example I mentioned earlier).

Comment: Did you ask your colleagues why they are using those global state libs? What about making a proof of concept and replace one of those in one of your projects by the approach you scetched and try out how well it works?

Comment: It's not hard to contrive a situation where the data doesn't come from a query or stored in a third party library which is as far as your discussion went.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing to use global state libraries like Redux or MobX in React often comes from past decisions and their benefits. Many older projects started with Redux because it was popular and now find it hard to switch. Redux is predictable and has tools that make debugging easier. It also has features, like middleware, that help manage complex tasks. While newer tools like `react-query` are great for fetching and storing data, Redux and MobX can handle a wider range of needs. They also have big communities, meaning lots of support and resources. For companies using Redux or MobX in many projects, it keeps things consistent for developers. But, it's true that for some projects, simpler tools might be better. The best choice depends on the project's needs and what the team knows best.